# Mount ContentDB

Tags: 2013, sql-server, web-application, content, database-attach

I am mounting a contentDB to a 2013 web application (upgrading from 2010).
The contentDB size is around 2,5GB , the mounting process is stucked.
I checked in the log and it is stucked here:

> InsertAllUserDataSparseDefaultRowOriginal Begin Upgrade()

The table AllUserData has around 5k records.
Any suggestions?

Comment: how you are mounting the database? using powershell?

Comment: yes, with powershell. Btw it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had just to wait.
It tooks almost 2 hours.
It needs time to **re-create the clustered index** on the table. (in my case AllDataUsers table has more than 5k items)